# How do I compile an extension for PHP 5.3 for windows as a DLL?

Tags: php, windows, dll, compilation, php-extension

I'm currently rewriting a `PHP` Extension that was originally written for `PHP 4.2.2.`  My issue is having the build/compile process generate a `.dll` instead of compiling the extension into the `PHP` core.  The environment is windows server 2003.  I'm using Visual Studio 2008.

I used the EXT_SKEL script to generate the framework, and I can succesfully compile the extension into the php core.  I'm trying to instead compile it as a `.dll` so I can easily distribute it to my clients.  Can anyone point me in the right direction for how to tell the `PHP 5.3` build process that i'd like to compile my extension as a `.dll` instead of staticly into `PHP` itself?

To build the extension's framework I run:

1. `php.exe` `ext_skel_win32.php --extname=myextension --proto=myprototypefile.dat`
2. Modified config.w32 to uncomment the 'ARG_ENABLE' line and make the default enabled
3. `buildconf.bat`
4. `cscript /nologo configure.js`
5. nmake

I confirm that I can run the extension's methods from within PHP, however it does not produce a distributable .dll.  instead it compiles the methods into the PHP binary.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
configure.js --enable-myextension=shared
```

edit: might also be

```
configure.js --with-myextension=shared
```

Comment: Thank you greatly for the quick response!