# PHP Modules - Compiling on Windows

Tags: php, dll, compilation

We are moving our server to a new server, and going from PHP 4.x to PHP 5.3. We need to add something like 10 extensions (php_pdf.dll, php_zip.dll, etc). I've Googled around, and it looks like I need to compile them, because all I can find is the source code for them. [This](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild) seems to be the best guide I can find for compiling an extension, but it looks like I need to also compile PHP to compile them. I already have PHP installed and configured though, so is there a way I can just compile the *.dll with the binary I already have for PHP?

Comment: Don't do this. You will loose your brain device's 40-year warranty. Seriously though, from my experience, every step was quite complicated. Even simply the tools required to build the extension, they're numerous and (wonder of wonders) all of them required...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see in the [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/de/install.pecl.windows.php), you can find the core extensions in the *php/ext/*-folder of your download and most of the other extensions in the [PECL-Library for windows](http://pecl4win.php.net/) (which currently is down). Last chance is downloading the [WAMPserver](http://www.wampserver.com) - your extensions may already be compiled there.

All other choices involves downloading the dlls from untrusted sources - I'd stick with compiling php then (while you will have to compile php completely, you may just use the dlls and keep your already installed php system). [This guide](http://blog.slickedit.com/2007/09/creating-a-php-5-extension-with-visual-c-2005/) will get you started.

Comment: I know where the core extensions are, and according to a bug ticket at php.net, that PECL Library site is and will stay offline. I have been able to successfully compile PHP and an extension, but can't seem to find the .dll from in the results.

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093921/how-do-i-compile-an-extension-for-php-5-3-for-windows-as-a-dll) answer, you need to enable the modules with a `--with-foobarextension=shared` to generate a dll instead of compiling it in the php.exe.