# How can I create a PHP extension on Windows?

Tags: php, c++, windows, wampserver

More specifically, I'm trying to make a PHP extension for WampServer, which I'm using to test PHP scripts on my PC. I know that a PHP extension requires a config.m4 file, and some C/C++ code to be created within PHP. How would I get these .c/.cpp and .m4 files into a .dll that's required to make a PHP extension?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://blog.slickedit.com/2007/09/creating-a-php-5-extension-with-visual-c-2005/), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093921/how-do-i-compile-an-extension-for-php-5-3-for-windows-as-a-dll), [this](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Cplusplus/Developing-Custom-PHP-Extensions-Part-1/) or [this](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild) will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this : [Getting Started with PHP Extension-Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311389/getting-started-with-php-extension-development)

Generally you need C compiler (with or without IDE), I recommend MS Visual C++ Express.
Then follow this tutorial: http://blog.slickedit.com/2007/09/creating-a-php-5-extension-with-visual-c-2005/

Comment: The last Link is dead